# WCF client does not assert that message is serializable

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am sending an object to a WCF service. The object is not known by the DataContractSerializer **neither** at client nor at service side. 
I would expect to get a serialization error at client side in this case, but instead, the send at client side succeeds, I only get no response from service (after the send timeout). 
I checked the WCF traces and saw that there is a de-serialization failure at the server side.

How do I force WCF client to to verify that the object to be send can be serialized?

Update: 
While trying to reproduce the problem in a simple scenario, I have managed to isolate it to relate to the "ReliableSession" configuration option. The problem occurs only when reliable session is enabled at either client or server side.

Please refer to this gist for demo:
https://gist.github.com/2291505

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContractSerializer` used by WCF is an "opt out" serializer, and will try and serialise all objects that you give it, whether or not they are marked with `[DataContract]` attributes. The only way to stop it is to explicitly mark up your objects with `[IgnoreDataMember]` attributes.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx) for more info about how `DataContractSerializer` will serialize your types.

Obviously your client is managing to serialize OK, otherwise WCF would error, but I assume the server side is not expecting something you are sending. Can you give any error info?

**EDIT:**
I suspect this is because you are sending an unknown type. The service end knows about strings so can successfully deserialise them, but knows nothing about a Person object so doesn't know what to do with it. (The client does know what a Person is, so can serialise it fine).

Try adding `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))]` to your service definition. Obviously the service will need access to the Person object for this to compile.

Comment: I made a code sample of the problem. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is that the serialization exception will be identified at client side in this case (when trying to send an unknown type). I still cannot understand why ReliableSession affects the desired behavior.